# Deployed application using InstallShield does not work

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, installshield

If you see below image, there are two applications deployed to IIS.

1. QManualDeployment - This is deployed using Visual studio **Publish** feature.
2. InstallShieldPOCWebApplication - This is deployed using **InstallShield** installation tool.

Option 1 is working without any issues, but as you see **InstallShieldPOCWebApplication** it looks like foder rather than web site. Also it does not work.

How can I deploy application as website using **INSTALLSHIELD**

[image]

Here is my **IIS Settings** from InstallShield Tool

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default Web Site is a website.  QManualDeployment is a virtual directory / application off of Default Web Site.

In InstallShield, it isn't enough to just author all of your directories/files into components.  You also have to define the IIS configuration.

I'm not sure if you are using InstallShield  Express, Professional/Premier  of Limited Edition so I can't give you more direction then that.

Comment: where and how to define IIS configurations? I am using InstallShield Professional 2018

Comment: http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/helplibrary/IISConfigView.htm#ref-views_590435047_1022576

Comment: I have updated the question with IIS settings. . Let me check the link provided.

Comment: The first question would be is it your intention to create a new website or to create an application under the default website?    This view pretty much looks like IIS so it should be self explanatory from there.

Comment: I have developed a website in Visual Studio 2017. I want to create installer so that it installs and configures the website in target system's IIS.  I want to create website under "Sites"

Comment: That's explained here: http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/helplibrary/IISVirtualRoots_Create.htm#configuringservers_377126794_1051223

Comment: FWIW, InstallShield can do this. But personally I no longer use InstallShield and instead do it this way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgDf1kv8a-4 https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials/tree/master/web-application   In the tutorial the "Explore IIS Support"  the XML is showing the IIS meta that you need to do in InstallShield through the IIS Server view.

Comment: looks great. I am going through it.

Comment: How do I integrate InstallShield with TFS? I mean I wish to autogenerate setup files during successful TFS checkin/release

Comment: Please ask this as a new question.

Comment: done https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48885522/auto-generating-installshield-setup-files-while-check-in-the-code

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue with Post owner, after run Install Shield setup file, it show a folder in IIS and I resolved by right click to folder name and convert to Application.

I share for whom concerned.

[image]

After that we can select suitable application pool as

[image]

Comment: we do not want to "convert to application" manually.   It shall be done using installer!

Comment: did you finish install shield job with automatically as web application yet? can you share how to do it, thanks