# How to auto generating setup file while check-in the code in to TFS

Tags: tfs, wix, continuous-integration, installshield, iswix

How do I integrate InstallShield/Wix/IsWix with TFS? I wish to auto generate setup files during successful TFS checkin/release?

I am comparing **[InstallShield](https://www.flexera.com/producer/products/software-installation/installshield-software-installer/)** with **[Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/)** and **[IsWix](http://iswix.com/projects/)**! to choose the right candidate for upcoming product development.

**Tools Used**

- v.Next Builds
- Team Foundation Version Control

Update from InstallShield support team

> To integrate InstallShield with Team Foundation Server, install InstallShield on each machine that u want to be able to create, update, or build InstallShield projects.It should also be installed on a machine that is designated as a build agent for InstallShield projects that are stored in Team Foundation Server.
>
> NOTE: The Standalone Build is a build engine that enables you to build InstallShield projects without installing the full version of InstallShield on a build machine.If you have the Standalone Build, you can install it on a machine that is designated as a build agent for Team Foundation Server."

Comment: InstallShield supports MSBuild.  Are you using XAML builds of v.Next Builds?

Comment: FWIW, IsWiX doesn't really matter in this scenario.  IsWiX merely creates WiX projects/code and doesn't get installed on the build server.  IsWiX does provide some additional code by default to support TFS builds so that just makes it a little easier up front but no big deal long term. WiX also supports MSBuild  so in this category  it's a tie between WiX and InstallShield.  They both support the use case.

Comment: I am using v.Next builds. Do u have any article/steps?

Comment: Git or TFVC? (The environment variables are different if I recall.)

Comment: Its Team Foundation Version Control.

Answer (score 2):

I have very limited experience with InstallShield, but I can advocate for WiX. Recently they added a [no-install option](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/daily_builds.html) that allows you to build WiX project by just adding a few files along to your sources.

WiX code is an XML dialect and it is simple to generate, but the simplest pattern is to write a Product and a Project file and let [Heat](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/heat.html) generating the remaining code you need for a simple install.

Comment: I much prefer Wix to InstallShield. When I used InstallShield the licensing became a real headache to maintain. With Wix you don't have to worry about the licensing, and it very powerful. You can easily customise it with your own CustomActions (written in C# etc).

Comment: where I can find step by step article ? it's help if it covers continuous integration with Wix

Comment: I already linked a couple of pages from WiX documentation which is pretty extensive. I suggest you to refine your original question or submit a new, more specific, one.

Answer (score 1):

At a high level  you need to create an .ISPROJ (MSbuild ) and .SLN for your .ISM. In the ISPROJ you'll want to write some code to regex parse the build number and generate a random ProductCode for major upgrades.

You'll add a build vs sln step to your build and tell it to use 32bit MSBuild (InstallShield doesn't support 64bit).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?tabs=batch

http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield22helplib/helplibrary/MSBuild.htm

You'll need an on-prem build server and install the InstallShield Stand Alone Build engine one it.  I'd go ahead and install the Automation Interface also as you don't know when you'll need it some day.

Comment: Updated the question with support response.  what does they mean?